# restoring the applications settings

Tags: partitioning, software-installation, system-settings

I am reinstalling Ubuntu with a separate home partition. I have been told that when I do this all the data in the home partition will not be harmed(when I use manual partitioning of course) and that all my "installed applications settings will remain".
If I want to reset these settings to their default without removing my data.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Open your home directory and type `Ctrl + H`. This will display all the hidden files, which start with a `.` character. These contain your settings. If you delete all of them, while keeping your personal files intact, your settings will be reset.